# What is wrong with my mongodb?

Tags: django, mongodb, locale, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I have a django project that requires mongo. When setting up my dev environment I get some error related to locale and mongo that I couldn't resolve.

```
$ bash -c ". ./host-install.sh && restore_mongodb ./social ~/Desktop/dump"
./host-install.sh: line 329: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (sv_SE.UTF-8): No such file or directory

*** 2015-05-07 09:51:53 dropping mongo storage social
Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.

*** 2015-05-07 09:51:53 unable to drop mongodb
(kthsocial)developer@developer-VirtualBox:/etc/social/social$
```

I tried the procedures mentioned in other questions for setting the locale but that didn't help. Can you please help me fix my installation?

Comment: Erm, are we supposed to guess what that `host-install.sh` does? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install language-pack-sv`

Comment: @YOU Thanks! That worked. If @-YOU post it as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install swedish locale.

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-sv
```